# cant activate virtual environment in ubuntu server

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have been learning python virtual environment and PIPs. I have installed python virtualenv in my ubuntu server using the following steps.

```
  pip install virtualenv

  ## Checking if its installed
   virtualenv --version
```

The file exists in the directory below. 
`virtualenv 20.16.5 from /home/coyo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/virtualenv/__init__.py`
I have specified it to use python3 interpreter

```
   virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 virtualenv_name
```

The problem comes in whenever i try to activate the virtual environment it throws an error no such file or directory.

```
   source virtualenv_name/bin/activate
```

I get this error:
`-bash: virtualenv_name/bin/activate: No such file or directory`

Comment: Any chance you are in the wrong directory? Is there a `virtualenv_name` directory?

Comment: Yes, I have that directory as my directory containing vern files that is (bin, include, lib, lib64,pyvenv)

Comment: And do you have the activate file under `bin`?

Comment: no inside bin I have (python,  python3) files only

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the built-in `venv` package?  On Ubuntu you need to install `python3-venv` and call it like `python3 -m venv name_of_new_venv`

Comment: Yes initially i had no buildin `vern` package. I had to install it and specify the python interpreter

Comment: Also virtualenv is a bit more flexible, it allows you to select specific python versions (different from the one used to run virtualenv)

Answer (score 0):

sometimes the activate file maybe located in another folder such as Scripts

locate for the 'activate' file in the virtualenv folder

Then try `source virtualenv_name/path_to_activate_file`

Comment: You can use the following command to find the file `find . -name activate`

Comment: @Ftagliacarne using that command the  file is located under (sud./home/coyo/.vim/bundle/ale/test/test-files/python/with_virtualenv/env/bin/activate)

Comment: What is your current directory/the dirctory of the virtualenv

Comment: @Ftagliacarne my current working directory is (/home/coyo/python/python_learning_tutorials/11-virtual_environment/virtual_env)

Comment: @Ftagliacarne how do i navigate to the file from my current directory?

Comment: You could do `cd FILE_PATH` but I have the feeling the path you posted earlier is not the correct one

Answer (score 0):

Building on Lamin's answer. Sometimes the activate file is located elsewhere. To find where it is you can run the following command:

```bash
find . -name activate
```

Where the `.` represents the current directory and the `-name activate` tells find to find a file called activate.

Once you know the file path you can activate the virtual env normally using

```bash
. virtualenv_name/PATH_TO_ACTIVATE
```